# Using PHP to avoid meaningless text in form fields

Tags: php, forms, validation, semantics

I tried to make php form script, which process data submitted by the user, but I want to find, how can I allow only meaning full text in those form fields   like "Honey" and other real meaning full user names

I mean, sometimes, user may enter its name like:  assalhdjsdyoeorsdhs.
although text entered is within allowed text length, but its not a name at all, so how to disallow such non-sense usernames, which created for just to submit an entry like in comments page also.

Comment: This is actually pretty damn hard!

Comment: I don't think there's an out-of-the-box solution for your problem.  The closest you can get to is to define a list of valid names and check the input against that list.  If it doesn't match - then a "bad" text is entered.

Comment: you are suggesting a whiteList security check, but I thought there may exist some faster black box testing type check in php.

Comment: I think you need a dictionary type script in your server side . Input will be checked with the dictionary elements . But it will take too long time ti validate the input .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only sure way of doing this is to have human intervention in the approval process for new users.

I don't know if that's an option for you, but a software based system is sure to be more trouble than just ignoring the problem.

I had a similar problem on a bulletin board I run, in the end I appointed some trusted users as admins and all new users had to be authorised manually. The problem was solved, but we don't have a high number of new users.

**Edit**

Another option I have just thought of is to use one of the methods suggested here to flag a user name for human attention.

Comment: I liked your solution. but I think, although its not possible in php, may be AI can help, I will search it out next.

Answer (score 5):

From a list of existing usernames, create a Markov chain on the likelyhood of the next letter. E.g. when you encounter the letter D, it is likely that the next letter is an E but it is nog likely that is is an M.

Then, check each new username against this Markov chain to determine the likelyhood that it is a normal username.

[image]

Comment: This is probably the most "right" answer, but you've still got the problem of creating the Markov chain in the first place. You need the data sets to build it with...

Answer (score 0):

you have to create database which will keep the relevant names.from where you can check every entry.it is not possible to prevent users for submitting words like "agasdffdssd"

Answer (score 0):

You could download a plain-text dictionary, and then check if the registered name is in that dictionary. Here is a sample website with dictionaries, including the English one: http://www.winedt.org/Dict/

Answer (score 0):

You must first define what you consider "meaningful". Is "Demla" meaningful? It might not be in the dictionary (at least not in the Dutch one :)  ), so you can't use that. You could parse for certain word-shapes, but you would have to take all the false positives or false negatives for granted. It won't be 100% at all. Is `Asd` a name? or the beginning of `ASDF`?

You could start something with a Markov chain, but you'd have a hard time getting it right and also explaining this to your users on false positives...

I'd filter problematic entries on other fields, and dissallow some basic stuff (like letters).

Answer (score 0):

http://www.haykranen.nl/2008/09/21/markov/  may this useful. it has `markov generator` with some source to download. try it.